# How to get the Mongo log information for particular range from Mongod.log file

Tags: mongodb

I have around 50GB Mongo log file in my cluster, for support purpose i need toshare last 10 days or range(from : this date to:that date) information to support team .

Can you tell me how to get the particular log information from log file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to extract this information using the [mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools) package, specifically using the [mlogfilter tool](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mlogfilter). The syntax would be similar to this:

```
mlogfilter mongod.log --from "end -10d" > Last10DaysMongoD.log
```